# Web API calling Error ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am developing a web api but it can not hit it. Error shows 404 not Found.

### Web Api

```
using Atea.Azure.ApiMangement.Business;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Azure_API_Delegation_Portal.Controllers
{
    [RoutePrefix("api/apim")]
    public class ApimController : ApiController
    {
        private readonly ISubscriptionService _subscriptionService;
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{string:productId}")]
        public bool GetProductSubscribe(string productId)
        {
            return _subscriptionService.IsSubscribed(productId);
        }
    }
}
```

How I call an API `https://localhost:44300/api/apim/ldkjfk232`

### Web API Route

```
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Azure_API_Delegation_Portal
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

### Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am missing this line of code in Application_Start() function in "Global.asax" file.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

Answer (score 1):

Fix your route template. It is string by default so no need for the string constraint

```cs
//GET api/apim/ldkjfk232"
[HttpGet]
[Route("{productId}")]
public bool GetProductSubscribe(string productId)
```

Also note that the constraint goes **after** the placeholder name like this example

```cs
[Route("{paramaterName:int}")]
```

Read more about attribute routing here : [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-)

It will show you how to properly configure your web api.

Comment: error remains the same after your suggested answer.